# Configure docker and docker-compose for more parallel running/starting containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**TL;DR:**
When starting **twelve containers in total** distributed over four docker-compose applications (each has three services defined) in parallel no matter how strong the hardware underneath is, this error occurs:

```
UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
```

Is there some configuration that limits or improves the docker engine parallel running/starting or docker socket read performance?

Upping the read timeout (like suggested on many forums) does not seem to be the right way to tackle this.

**Long version:**

I am using docker-compose to start my themed application for integration testing.

During this integration-test process, every client is started and tested with their personalized test files.

The docker-compose file consists of three services:

- PHP
- MySQL
- Neo4j

All images are simply prefilled public library docker images.

Since the application takes quite some time to start (because the databases take a long time to start) I parallelized the process so three applications could run in parallel.

A simplified example of the starting process would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
clients=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e")
declare -A pids
pids=()
for client in "${clients[@]}"; do
    joblist=($(jobs -p))
    while
        ((${#joblist[*]} >= 3))
    do
        sleep 1
        joblist=($(jobs -p))
    done
    {
        docker-compose -f $client/docker-compose.yml up -d
        #wait for mysql
        while ! docker-compose -f $client/docker-compose.yml exec -T mysql isAlive.sh; do
            sleep 1
        done
        #wait for neo4j
        while ! docker-compose -f $client/docker-compose.yml exec -T neo4j isAlive.sh; do
            sleep 1
        done
        #run tests
        for i in $client/tests/*.yml; do
            if ! runTest $i; then
                exit 1
            fi
        done
    } &
    pids["$client"]="$!"
done
for p in "${!pids[@]}"; do
    if ! wait "${pids[$p]}"; then
        echo "error with $p"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

When running these tests in a virtual machine (6 virtual CPUs, dedicated SSD storage and 48 GB RAM) the parallelization at three tests was robust. Everything above that started returning errors like these

```
UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
```

I thought this had to do with the performance of the virtual machine,
 now I upgraded to a bare-metal machine (2x 8 core CPUs @over 3GHz/core, 60 GB RAM, SSD storage) and this issue still occurs although the utilization of all components (CPU, RAM, storage network [checked myself and with my host]) is minimal.

Raising the read timeout does not seem to be the right solution because there is some error in utilizing the full performance the server has to offer. It might be some docker configuration or limitation, I was not able to find anything concerning this.

Comment: That reads like something is backing up in the Docker daemon itself.  What does `some code to wait for the service to be ready` do?  If it does things like `docker ps`, in a tight loop, I could see eventually hitting issues like this.

Comment: @DavidMaze I extended the code sample to cover your question.
why could you see hitting an issue like this even if the underlying bare-metal system is so much more powerful? is there any way to prevent this except from rewriting the code to not use docker commands?